# Duplicate method call or add logic to set local variables as parameters?

Tags: c#

This is a fairly trivial example of a question I come up to often.  In the example below I tend to think that allowing duplication sometimes results in clearer code.

Does anyone agree/disagree on this point?

First way: an additional local variable is used so `method.Invoke` is called just once on the last line. *I think this has slightly more logic to decode than the second way.*

```
private static void Invoke<T>(string[] args, MethodInfo method) where T : new()
{
    T target = new T();
    target.InvokeMethod("Initialize", errorIfMethodDoesNotExist: false, accessNonPublic: true);
    string[] methodArgs = null;
    if (args.Length > 1)
    {
        methodArgs = args.Skip(1).ToArray();
    }
    method.Invoke(target, methodArgs);
}
```

Second way: No additional local variable but the call to `method.Invoke` is duplcated in both branches of the if statement.  *I think this is clearer even though logic was duplicated.*

```
private static void Invoke<T>(string[] args, MethodInfo method) where T : new()
    {
        T target = new T();
        target.InvokeMethod("Initialize", errorIfMethodDoesNotExist: false, accessNonPublic: true);
        if (args.Length > 1)
        {
            method.Invoke(target, args.Skip(1).ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            method.Invoke(target, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I personally like your first option in this case as for me it reads easier and is actually less logic in my view to decode as such

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this would be even better, in this case.

```
private static void Invoke<T>(string[] args, MethodInfo method) where T : new()
{
    T target = new T();
    target.InvokeMethod(
        "Initialize", errorIfMethodDoesNotExist: false, accessNonPublic: true);
    string[] methodArgs = args.Skip(1).ToArray();
    method.Invoke(target, methodArgs);
}
```

[`Skip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) on an empty collection returns an empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

or if you want to keep the `null` value, you can inline the things in the method call with a ternary `if` like this :

```
method.Invoke(target, args.Length > 1 ? args.Skip(1).ToArray() : null);
```

Not super effective here considering svick answer, but in a more general case I think it is preferable to your two options (as long as it doesn't makes you write a 200 characters line).